# send OracleDBtype.Date parameter to procedure in c#

Tags: c#, oracle, type-conversion

I try to send Date object to Oracle Procedure but it just give me date as 01-JAN-00 .
I use this to send it with custom designed connection but it get END_DATE as 01-JAN-00.

dbcontext.AddParameter(OracleDbType.Date, ParameterDirection.Input, endTime.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"), parameterName: "END_DATE");

how could I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't cast your `DateTime` endTime value `endTime.ToString`. Just pass it as is